# What is the phrase that means a quality that is "constant throughout" a larger thing

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to say: throughout someone's life, hard work was a constant theme and I was going to use:"his whole life was underscored by hard work" but I'm pretty sure that's not what that means at all and it might not even make sense. Does anyone know what phrase I'm looking for?

Comment: *Persistent* is a good word for this.

Comment: @Xanne: 'Persistent' is not idiomatic English in this context.

Comment: Your choices are correct, idiomatic English. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Consistent = acting or done in the same way over time, especially so as to be fair or accurate.
"the parents are being consistent and firm in their reactions" (Google)

Comment: Mozibur I didn't know that underscored could actually be used in this way it just popped into my head

Comment: One of the meanings of *underscore* is the musical accompaniment to movie scene or libretto. It is this sense that you are using a little metaphorically, and it is just fine as it stands. Hard work has accompanied his entire life.

Answer (score 1):

You actually said it: A constant.

This phasing is common to describe a quality that doesn't change.

*Throughout his life, despite changes in circumstances, hard work was a constant.*

*Throughout his life, the only constant was his dedication to hard work.*

The question might be, was this character forced to work hard, eager to work hard, stuck working hard? What is hard work? Is it the effort you put into it, or unfortunate circumstances, such as terrible conditions, horrible bosses, physical labor? Just saying "hard work was a constant" in someone's life does not give much insight into either the work or the person.

Comment: Constant is better than the other answers, most of which refer to something that recurs rather than something which is ever-present.

Answer (score 0):

“Hard work was pervasive throughout his entire life”?
“Hard work permeated …”

Underscored, to me, makes it sound like it was *because* of hard work that his life was possible/practical/desirable.

Maybe a bit more context. What was it about hard work that altered his life?

Comment: He was born on a farm and through relentless hard work managed to fund his own higher education and build a career, and just works hard in all aspects of his life basically

Answer (score 0):

... 'his whole life was predicated on hard work.'

'Predicated' with the meaning of 'based on'.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **keynote**.

> *keynote* [noun]
>
> 1. a prevailing tone or central theme ....
>
> - *Individuality is the keynote of the Nineties.*
>
> ...

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/keynote)]

'Hard work was the keynote of his life.'

One could also use 'Hard work was the defining feature of his life' or 'his life was defined by hard work'.

Answer (score 0):

> Hard work was the **cornerstone** of his entire life.

> A basic element : FOUNDATION
> *A  cornerstone of foreign policy* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cornerstone)

> The cornerstone of something is the basic part of it on which its
> existence, success, or truth depends. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/cornerstone)

> Something that is essential, indispensable, or basic.
> *The cornerstone
> of democratic government is a free press.* [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cornerstone)

---

> ... but "despite all the motley features of Peter's character, his was
> a surprisingly whole nature. The idea of serving the state, in which
> the tsar profoundly believed and to which he subordinated his
> activities, was the **cornerstone** of his life." P. P. Pavlenko,
> quoted in D. J. Raleigh and A. A. Iskenderov; *The Emperors and
> Empresses of Russia*

> The city was the sphere of both morality and politics and Socrates'
> commitment to improving his fellow citizens was the **cornerstone** of
> his life... [Vijay Tankha; *Ancient Greek Philosophy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ancient_Greek_Philosophy_2_e/ashoBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22was%20the%20cornerstone%20of%20his%20life%22&pg=PA332&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score -1):

You could say

> Hard work was the ***leitmotif*** of his whole life.

***Leitmotif*** is used here metaphorically:

> A leitmotif in something such as a book or film or ***in a person's life*** ***is an idea or an object which occurs again and again***. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leitmotif))
>
> - There is no doubt that the system will need reform, and that reform will be *the leitmotiv of politics* over the next decade. (From the Hansard archive - [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leitmotiv))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leitmotif) notes about *leitmotif*:

> *Leitmotif* is still commonly used with reference to music and musical drama but is now also *used more broadly to refer to any recurring theme in the arts or in everyday life.*
>
> - His passion for running was the leitmotif of his life. (New York Times)